# Fragment Navigation delay - Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-glide, androidimageslider

In my app I have custom bottom navigation bar with 4 menu item (Home, wash, crown, menu). Default screen was Home. When I click wash, crown, menu the respective fragment/screen loaded quick. But when I click Home from any of these (wash, crown, menu) screen, it takes around a second to switch to that screen. I have a recycler view, a image slider view, both with around 5-6 data. And a Linear layout with some elements. Even I have animation in bottom bar navigation button, when I click home animations wasn't smooth. but for other menu items it was smooth. What is the reason for this Delay.

Sometime Every time logcat print this, when I switch to home.

*"2023-12-12 18:19:02.171 28866-28866 ViewTarget           com.csam.demodev

Glide treats LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT as a request for an image the size of this device's screen dimensions. If you want to load the original image and are ok with the corresponding memory cost and OOMs (depending on the input size), use override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL). Otherwise, use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, set layout_width and layout_height to fixed dimension, or use .override() with fixed dimensions.*

[Here is The code for this Fragment](https://gist.github.com/SanjayAIT16/685ba179c9cd2b195923d655148592c7)

Comment: Delays are probably due to the time to get data from the server and the time to add data to the view.  The time to get data from the server includes 1) Size of Database 2) Amount of data to transfer over the connection, the type of connection, the speed of the connection, the amount of memory for the database.  Speed is also dependent on the type of database and if the database is fragmented.   You do not want to use Excel on a very large database.  You also want to make sure a large database is on a machine with a fast hard drive, lots of memory, and a fast processor with lots of cores.

Comment: @jdweng Actually Now i have a data of very small amount, even the data are not from server. I added a list of words in array list and show it in recycler view. And for Image Slider I have added a single image, and duplicated it using 10 times but it doesn't matter, even when I use single image of very low size around 10KB it still has delay.

Comment: You have to determine if the long time is due to getting the image or displaying the image.